# Not setting host header

Tags: php, curl

I have a PHP script that primes my website cache.

I'm trying to bypass the Nginx frontend and grab the headers from the Apache backend.

The following example works (via command line) :

```
curl -I -H "Host: example.com" 127.0.0.1
```

However, when I try to do the same in PHP - it does not.

```
$headers = array("Host: example.com");
$url = "127.0.0.1";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$ret = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

echo "$ret";
```

This always returns the first website listed in my apache virtualhost files - not the website listed in the 'host' http headers.

Any idea why it works just fine via command line - but not in the php script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible at all, however what I would try is to pass the URL at init:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
```

And then *not* with `curl_setopt`. It's just a suggestion to test, no guarantee this helps. So more a lengthy comment.

You can also enable verbose mode and *see* what specifically curl sends for request headers, I have outlined this in an answer here: [Bad Request. Connecting to sites via curl on host and system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9571305/367456). This should show what is going on behind the curtain, very useful if you do not yet sniff the network traffic.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check out the link and see if I can figure out what is happening.

Comment: Take a look if you can gather the verbose output. You can add it to your question, that should make your problem description more concrete.

Answer (score -1):

I think [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#53445) is the answer.

"Do this instead:

```
$host = "www.example.com"; 
$url = "http://$host/"; 

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

"

Comment: I assume that Dave wants to explicitly set the `Host:` request header different to the IP address. E.g. to pass a hostname that does not resolve to that IP or for testing purposes.