# How can I get the redirected domain?

Tags: php, redirect

I made a script to get some urls, in fact when this script for example get abcd.com and  efgh.com this domain is redirected to zxyw.com and I want just to get zxyw.com like result
my question is how to get the redirected domain with PHP

Comment: Do you mean which of the following domains did the user come from?

Comment: Please precise if you want the referer or the active domain. And look to $_SERVER doc. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] gives you the active domain, and $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] gives you the referer.

Comment: If you have the curl extension installed, you can use the curl handle and obtain the *effective url*, that is the one you're looking for:     `$urlEndpoint = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);` - see as well http://stackoverflow.com/a/9571305/367456

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to get the complete URL of where the user came from.

Comment: do you have an example please

Comment: Hi @YassirGourram - just assign this to a variable it and you should see what it looks like :)
`$lastUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`
`var_dump($lastUrl);`
Hope that makes it clear :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do then something like this should work. Assuming **you have the curl extension installed:**

```
   <?php
   $ch = curl_init("http://www.link1.com/whatever");

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   $header = "Location: ";
   $pos = strpos($response, $header);
   $pos += strlen($header);
   $redirect_url = substr($response, $pos, strpos($response, "\r\n", $pos)-$pos);
   echo $redirect_url;
   ?>
```

Comment: *If* I would have the curl extension installed I would have done it differently, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/14436877/367456 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9571305/367456

Comment: That is an exact copy paste from this [**answer**](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3681920.htm). Please add the source from where you copied the content from. Thanks :)

Comment: you code return sometimes **00 OK**

Comment: @YassirGourram: That code is fragile. [See my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591875/how-to-get-the-redirected-domain#comment36210581_23591875) how it works if you're using curl.

Comment: Yes, it is a cut& paste I've tried on my test server what's wrong?

Comment: BTW, I think ther is a good starting point to appreciatre the problem.
Dear colleague your contribute will allways appreciated. ciao