# php CURL cant set content-type

Tags: php, symfony, curl, symfony3.x

I want to login the user when registration success.
I'm using Symfony 3 with fos_user.
This is the registration code:

```
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->createUser();
$user->setUsername($username);
$user->setPlainPassword($password);
$user->setEmail($email);
$role = "ROLE_USER";
$user->setRoles(array($role));
$user->setEnabled(true);
$user->setName($name);
$userManager->updateUser($user);
```

Now im trying to login user with CURL like this:

```
//LOGIN THE USER 
$data = array(
      '_username' => $username,
      '_password' => $password,
      '_remember_me' => false
);
$url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_check');
$ch = curl_init($url);
$postString = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But this code don´t login the user and the /login_check action, returns me to /login page.
[image]
I try with "REST CLIENT" and I can login the user by setting content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but i think that CURL is not setting the content type because when I print "curl_getinfo($ch);" returns this:

```
[url] => http://192.168.1.100/web/app_dev.php/login_check
[content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 302
[header_size] => 401
[request_size] => 222
...
```

I comment "csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager" in "security.yml" to login without TOKEN.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the output if you enable the verbose option? `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);`

Comment: HI Jim, the result is the same.

Comment: Adding the verbose option will not change the return value. You need to check your logs. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868808/make-curl-output-stderr-to-file-or-string). Update your question with the contents of that file.