# how to get json data from 8080 port in php

Tags: json, curl

I am using CURL function in php.
i get json data from 8080 port , but return only empty value..
how to get json data from 8080 port 
below the link are using in CURL functions...

```html
<?php 

$url = 'https://example.com:8080/getdata/?format=json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headr);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: you use CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, maybe the problem is that you're simply not printing $result ?  what do you get if you add `var_dump($result);` after `$result = curl_exec($ch);`  ?

Comment: yes i use echo $result or var_dump($result) .But not show output only return empty value...!

Comment: then what does CURLOPT_VERBOSE tell you? if it tells you nothing, that means you can't see STDERR info for some reason, so add `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_STDERR,STDOUT);` and re-run it. (this will redirect curl's stderr to stdout, which should enable you to view it)

Comment: hanshenrik, I am using `curl_setopt(CUR_STDERR,$stdout);` . this is functions not working. And I try another method `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION ,true )`, also not workng .Return only empty value. Please update any other idea ...

Comment: what is $stdout ? what does `var_dump($stdout);`  return?

Comment: first i try `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_STDERR,STDOUT);` this code error , than find related solutions and use `curl_setopt(CUR_STDERR,$stdout);`  . `$stdout` is file elements.  get from  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868808/make-curl-output-stderr-to-file-or-string).

Comment: weird, are you running a *very* old version of PHP? like PHP 5.2 from 2006? because `STDOUT` should work from PHP 5.3 (released in 2009) and newer..

Comment: localhost server is running in my machine. An only live server is not running ...

Comment: and what does `<?php phpinfo(~0); ?>`  return?